# How can I adjust progressbar layout inside select in angular material

Tags: css, angular-material

I have the following angular material code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
  <md-input-container>
    <label>SOME_LABEL</label>
    <md-select ng-model="some.model">
      <md-option value="SOME_OPTION_HERE" ng-disabled="$index === 1">
        SOME_OPTION_HERE
        <md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="25"></md-progress-linear>
      </md-option>
      <md-option value="SOME_OTHER_OPTION_HERE" ng-disabled="$index === 1">
        SOME_OTHER_OPTION_HERE
        <md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="35"></md-progress-linear>
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

It shows the progressbars at the bottom of the option, but they are not 100% wide when select dropdown is visible. Also when an option is selected the progress bar is clipped vertically. How can I show the complete progressbar height after option is selected and show progressbar with 100% width?

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdjaeK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `width` of `md-option ._md-text` to `100%`, instead of `auto`.

It then takes the full width of the element it's in, instead of the width the name that the option has.

```
md-option ._md-text {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit**

The other issue is because of the height of `._md-select-value *:first-child`. I updated my CodePen to address this problem as well.

```
._md-select-value {
  height: 50px; /*Set height for select */
}

._md-select-value *:first-child {
  height: 30px; /*Set height for selected value (including bar)
}
```

See my *updated* CodePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGzqxb

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @RamandeepSingh Glad I could help. Be sure to use  the *web inspector* of your favourite browser to investigate what's going on in your application.

Comment: I am new to css, it just didn't strike me to look up the web inspector. *embarrassed smiley here*. Now I looked it up and it does make sense. Thanks again.